# Game object not visible in game view

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

in my game i added a simple game object to follow my player , but the problem is it is not showing the follower when i click play , i'm new to unity , can any one help me  . ill be attaching the script that i tried and output screenshot that i'm getting now.

(the follower is visible in scene window , disappears when i click play button)

[image]

script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FollowPlayer : MonoBehaviour {


public GameObject playerobj ;
public float smoothtime = 0.3f ;
Vector2 velocity = Vector2.zero;

public int yoffset;

void Start () {

}

void Update () {

    Vector2 targetPosition = playerobj.transform.TransformPoint(new 
    Vector3(0,yoffset));
    if(targetPosition.y < transform.position.y)
    return;
    targetPosition = new Vector3(0 , targetPosition.y);
    transform.position = Vector2.SmoothDamp(transform.position,targetPosition,ref velocity,smoothtime);
    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x ,transform.position.y ,-10) ;

}
}
```

thanks in advance guys !

Comment: may be you must new and initialize GameObject  at Start

Comment: Check Your camera transform position (set z to -100 for example)

Comment: thanks for your suggestions but still , i can't find the solution

Answer (score 0):

You should check the object's layer and camera's layer mask

Comment: Really checked? I guess that round icon is a part of UI, and the other UI elements are not shown in the scene view. so you should put the icon in the range of the UI camera.

Comment: If you still don't see it, please provide more infomation. there are tons of reason make an object dispeared.

Answer (score 0):

after doing so many search and reference i finally got a working solution.
i changed these values in update method. hope my answer helps some one.

```
void Update () {

    Vector2 targetPosition = playerobj.transform.TransformPoint(new Vector3(0,yoffset));
    if(targetPosition.y < transform.position.y)
    return;
    targetPosition = new Vector2(0 , targetPosition.y-8);
    transform.position = Vector2.SmoothDamp(transform.position,targetPosition,ref velocity,smoothtime);
    transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x ,transform.position.y) ;

}
```